# Problem in getting test ethers from sepolia faucet by alchemy

Tags: blockchain, ether, alchemy, faucets, sepolia

I am getting error
**"Sorry! To be fair to all developers, we only send 1 Sepolia ETH every 24 hours. Please try again after 24 hours from your original request."**

on sepolia and mumbai faucets by alchemy
(https://sepoliafaucet.com/ & https://mumbaifaucet.com/) ,

**my account - 0x9ec039BEeF508169d84e53777874e2C34dfC06a4**

even though its been more than 24hours since I last collected the test ethers with my account .

This address is available on sepolia & mumbai testnet.

I am attaching error images from sepolia faucet and transaction screenshot from sepolia.etherscan

[image: Sepolia faucet error]

[image: Sepolia.etherscan transaction history]

Answer (score 1):

if its real what you are saying, then its strange it should be allow you to withdraw the faucets after 24 hours.
It's possible that the faucet has a limit on the total amount of test ether it can distribute in a day, and once that limit is reached, no more withdrawals can be made until the limit resets. However, you can try these https://sepolia-faucet.pk910.de/, https://faucet.sepolia.dev/ alternatives to mine some faucets.